# no such file to load -- sinatra/session (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos, sinatra

I can't run the ruby web application, and I get this message error:

```
rackup webapp/config.ru --debug
nil
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31 - no such file to load -- sinatra/base
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31 - no such file to load -- sinatra/session
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:38 - no such file to load -- sinatra/session
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49 - no such file to load -- sinatra/session
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sinatra/session (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/local/deployer/webapp/config.ru:3
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/deployer/webapp/config.ru:0:in `new'
        from /usr/local/deployer/webapp/config.ru:0
```

It seems like it cannot find where sinatra is.
My config.ru is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/session'
require './lib/miscsystem'
require './lib/deployer'

run Deployer
```

- I did a : gem install sinatra

Here is the output of #gem env

```
# gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Any help?

Comment: Problem solved using : gem install sinatra-session

Answer (score 1):

problem solved using:

```
gem install sinatra-session
```